# how do I (re)create an object of type 'language'?

Tags: r, formula

Consider the following problem: `ff` is a formula with some fancy stuff in it; as a result the `variables` attribute of `terms(ff)` won't contain the raw variables, but rather the fancy stuff, e.g.

```
ff <- ~I(Age)+poly(q,3)
str(attr(terms(ff),"variables"))
## language list(I(Age), poly(q, 3))
```

I'm trying to hack this attribute into `list(Age,q)` **as a `language` object**.  I can get partway there:

```
(vlist <- lapply(as.list(all.vars(ff)),as.name))
## [[1]]
## Age   
## [[2]]
## q
str(vlist)
## List of 2
##  $ : symbol Age
##  $ : symbol q
```

but I'm stumped on turning this back into a `language` object.  I've played around a lot with `deparse`, `substitute`, `bquote`, `as.call` ... but can't quite get the right incantation, e.g.

```
deparse(vlist)
## [1] "list(Age, q)"    ## character, not language
parse(text=deparse(vlist))
## expression(list(Age, q))   ## expression, not language
as.name(vlist)
## Error in as.name(vlist) : 
##   (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'symbol'
```

`dput(vlist)` *looks* good, but it's just printing to the console and not changing the object ...

A little bit more context: I'm running into trouble downstream within `model.matrix`, where it checks

```
reorder <- match(sapply(attr(t, "variables"), deparse2)[-1L], 
        names(data))
```

(where `deparse2` is a wrapper for `deparse` that collapses stuff to a single string).  I *might* be able to get away with setting the `variables` attribute to `NULL` (so nothing would "not match"), but otherwise I have to set it to something that will be `deparse`-able and will match the variables in the new data frame ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were on the right track with `parse` and `deparse`:

```
(lang <- parse(text=deparse(lapply(all.vars(ff), as.name)))[[1]])
# list(Age, q)
str(lang)
# language list(Age, q)
```

Answer (score 3):

There might be a better way, but this seems to work:

```
> (lang <- do.call("call", c("list", lapply(all.vars(ff), as.name)), quote=TRUE))
list(Age, q)
> str(lang)
 language list(Age, q)
```

Here's an alternative, which might be slightly-cleaner:

```
> (lang <- as.call(c(quote(list), lapply(all.vars(ff), as.name))))
list(Age, q)
> str(lang)
 language list(Age, q)
```

Answer (score 3):

An alternative way(change the terms of the original call):

```
lang <- attr(terms(ff),"variables")
lang[-1] <-lapply(all.vars(ff),as.name)
str(lang)
language list(Age, q)
```

Another way (it is equivalent to Joshua's second suggestion):

```
lang <- c(quote(list), lapply(all.vars(ff),as.name))
mode(lang) <- "call"
str(lang)
language list(Age, q)
```